# How to get 'primary' MAC address on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want my program to get primary MAC address on my user's computer and send it to my server when user login, so I can limit my program only run on 2 devices (like evernote)

I tried to use [GetAdaptersAddresses function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx), but it gave me multiple network adapter information. Here's the output:

> ```
>     ...
>     Length of the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESS struct: 376
>     IfIndex (IPv4 interface): 4
>     Adapter name: {1DF5C314-BE85-4804-B653-D3E5F98F5231}
>     Number of Unicast Addresses: 2
>     No Anycast Addresses
>     Number of Multicast Addresses: 10
>     Number of DNS Server Addresses: 3
>     DNS Suffix:
>     Description: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
>     Friendly name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
>     Physical address: 00-50-56-C0-00-08
>     Flags: 453
>     Mtu: 1500
>     IfType: 6
>     OperStatus: 1
>     Ipv6IfIndex (IPv6 interface): 4
>     ZoneIndices (hex): 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
>     Transmit link speed: 100000000
>     Receive link speed: 100000000
>     Number of IP Adapter Prefix entries: 8
>
>     Length of the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESS struct: 376
>     IfIndex (IPv4 interface): 9
>     Adapter name: {65CE3D53-968E-410E-8C47-E0BACBC3D42B}
>     Number of Unicast Addresses: 2
>     No Anycast Addresses
>     Number of Multicast Addresses: 10
>     Number of DNS Server Addresses: 3
>     DNS Suffix:
>     Description: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
>     Friendly name: vEthernet (      
>     Physical address: **BC-85-56-8F-3B-0B**
>     Flags: 453
>     Mtu: 1500
>     IfType: 6
>     OperStatus: 1
>     Ipv6IfIndex (IPv6 interface): 9
>     ZoneIndices (hex): 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
>     Transmit link speed: 54000000
>     Receive link speed: 54000000
>     Number of IP Adapter Prefix entries: 8
>     ...
> ```

I can see the second one on my route. It is the one I'm looking for, but how can I distinguish it from the others?

What I want is a single MAC which should be:

1. The network adapter should have **connectivity** (I can see it from 'View your network properties' on Windows, but don't know how to pragmatically get it)
2. Not the 'VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8'
3. Program can get the same MAC after restart, even after OS re-installation

I found [Detect-Internet-Network-Availability](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64975/Detect-Internet-Network-Availability), maybe network stat on network adapter interface could be one of the factors to identify the 'primary' network adapter I want. But it was written in C#.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no single MAC which meets these conditions.

Comment: Why don't you extract the MAC address from the socket (in your client), once you have made a connection to your server? Why even deal with the (unanswerable) question on how to specify, what a *"primary MAC address"* is supposed to be.

Comment: @IInspectable Good idea, let me have a try.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using cpprestsdk library of MS to communicate client with web server, it is a HTTP lib. I don't know if I could get socket from it.

Comment: Which would you consider the "primary" for a laptop user who sometimes connects through the ethernet jack and sometimes through WiFi?  Did they just use up their two-device limit?

Comment: I would consider they are same device. So the device identifying is the purpose (MAC is just one option)

Comment: @user1633272: If you can access the underlying socket, you can get its local IP from `getsockname()`. But if not, you can use `GetTcp(6)Table2()` or `GetExtendedTcpTable()` to enumerate open TCP connections, looking for connections that belong to your process ID and are connected to the REST server's IP/Port. That will give you the local IP(s) of those connection(s). Once you have a local IP, you can enumerate the local network adapters with `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` looking for that IP, and when you find it you will have its MAC.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like doable, don't know if it is reliable. What I am looking for is a unique device ID to limit the user can only login on limited devices, maybe I should use some other system IDs rather than MAC.

Comment: @user1633272: MACs can certainly be spoofed. So can just about anything else you come up with (especially considering that whatever you decide on has to be transmitted to the REST server for validation). The only thing the REST server can retrieve on its own is the IP/Port that the client is connecting from. Anything else is dependent on the client, which means a malicious client can send whatever it wants. So you are likely best off simply having the REST server limit the user account to two concurrent logins regardless of the devices being used.

Comment: I end up with 'MachineGuid' since it is easy to obtain and more reliable.